# where to control view controllers?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, xcode

i'm working in view-based template,
and I have main.m, which I haven't touched.
and one view controller which is my current display,
and one dummy controller which has nothing.

If I implement the dummy controller, and want to switch between 
two view controllers, where and how should I do it?
I've only worked with subviews, 
but not quite sure where to touch the view controllers...
does it work the same as addView, release as with subviews?
Please help me out..

Comment: What is your target: Mac OS or iOS?

Comment: Just fyi user608996, Xcode is simply an integrated development environment (IDE). You can develop iOS apps, Mac apps, or most anything with C, C++, Objective-C, Java, AppleScript, Python, or Ruby, and with the appropriate plugins, C#, Haskell, D, Fortan, Ada, etc. Just "Xcode" doesn't tell us enough to know. @Bavarious added tags to your question for clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how you want you're looking to do.   You could present your dummy view controller either modally or non-modally.  To do it modally, check out:

```
- (void)presentModalViewController:(UIViewController *)modalViewController animated:(BOOL)animated
```

Here is a sample on how you would do something like that:

```
DummyViewController *dummyController = [[DummyViewController alloc] init];
[self presentModalViewController: dummyController];
```

You could also do something like:

```
- (void)presentFlipSideViewController:(UIViewController *)flipsideViewController
```

You would call these methods when the user did something, such as tap a button.  Both of these methods would be implemented in the view controller handling the tap or action, in your case, the project template view controller .